# Converting a regular expression to a context-free grammar

Tags: regular-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, regular-expressions

Does this conversion look right? I am learning conversion from RE to CFG.

RE:

$$(a \cup b)^* \cup ab(a \cup b)^*$$

CFG:

*Terminals:*
$$ S_1 \to a \\ S_2 \to b $$

*This is for the first $(a + b)^*$:*

\begin{align}
&S_3 \to S_1 \mid S_2 && (a \cup b) \\
&S_4 \to S_3S_4 \mid \epsilon && (a \cup b)^*
\end{align}

*This is for the $ab$ in the middle:*

$$ S_5 \to a \\ S_6 \to b $$

*This is for the second $(a \cup b)$ and $(ab)$ in the middle:*

\begin{align}
&S_7 \to S_1 \mid S_2 && (a \cup b) \\
&S_8 \to S_7S_8 \mid \epsilon && (a \cup b)^* \\
&S_9 \to S_5 S_6 && (ab)
\end{align}

*Concatenated $ab$ with the second $(a \cup b)^*$:*

\begin{align}
&S_{10} \to S_8 S_9 && (ab(a \cup b)^*)
\end{align}

*This the final CFG:*

\begin{align}
&S_{11} \to S_4 \mid S_{10} && (a \cup b)^* \cup ab(a \cup b)^*
\end{align}

Comment: Please use MathJax formatting (https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) instead of code formatting for mathematic formulae.

Comment: The point of the algorithm for converting a regular expression to a context-free grammar is that *it is completely mechanical*. A computer could do it, *literally*. No creativity is required. If you follow its steps, then you have applied it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

This CFG is indeed correct, but can be greatly simplified.

- First, there is no need to create a new variable that would derive only a terminal value, that is - $s_1,s_2,s_5,s_6$ are not required.
- For a similar reason, we don't need $s_9$.
- Another simplification is that $(a\cup b)^*$ was already generated by $s_4$. There is no need to create $s_7$ and $s_8$ for this usage

Considering those things, the CFG will be reduced to:

- $S\rightarrow A\space|\space abA$
- $A \rightarrow AB\space|\space\epsilon$
- $B \rightarrow a\space |\space b$

Notice also that $L(ab(a\cup b)^*)\subseteq L((a\cup b)^*)$, and thus:

$L((a\cup b)^*\cup ab(a\cup b)^*) = L((a\cup b)^*) \cup L(ab(a\cup b)^*) = L((a\cup b)^*)$

And thus an even smaller CFG will be:

- $S \rightarrow A$
- $A \rightarrow AB \space | \space \epsilon$
- $B \rightarrow a\space | \space b$

Essentially we removed one unnecessary derivation rule. This can be simplified a bit further, go ahead and give it a try :)

Comment: thank you. Our professor wants us to do it this way. I did not know I could reuse s4 instead of creating s7 and s8.

Comment: @Legend7 i have updated the answer a bit, take a look at it again :)

Answer (score 0):

As @nir_shahar said the mentioned language is equivalent to $L((a \cup b)^*)$, hence the grammar may be written much simpler:

$$ S \rightarrow aS | bS| \epsilon $$

Comment: I think the idea was for OP to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's right. You just read the sub-expressions from bottom up; but do bear in mind, there are only 7 distinct sub-expressions, not 10. They are:
$$A = a, B = b, C = A∪B, D = C^*, E = AB, F = ED, G = D∪F.$$
So, the grammar could just as well be written as:
$$A → a, B → b, C → A, C → B, D → ε, D → DC,\\E → AB, F → ED, G → D, G → F, G,$$
with the top-level expression, as indicated at the end, being $G$. The $=$'s become $→$'s, the unions split ($q = r∪s$ becomes $q→r, q→s$), and the stars recurse ($q = r^*$ becomes $q→ε, q→qr$ or $q→ε, q→rq$ or even $q→ε, q→qrq$).

Since all regular expressions have finite right-affine grammars (which count as context-free grammars), you can also write them that way, by adopting certain algebraic rules. This time, set the top-level expression to:
$$A = (a∪b)^* ∪ ab(a∪b)^*.$$
Then, after using the identity $x^* = ε ∪ x x^*$ and distributivity $x(y∪z) = xy∪xz$, as well as associativity $x(yz) = (xy)z$, we have:
$$(a∪b)^* = ε ∪ (a∪b)(a∪b)^* = ε ∪ a(a∪b)^* ∪ b(a∪b)^*
\\ab(a∪b)^* = a\left(b(a∪b)^*\right)
$$
and, from this, we get:
$$A = ε ∪ a\left(b(a∪b)^* ∪ (a∪b)^*\right) ∪ b\left((a∪b)^*\right) = ε ∪ aB ∪ bC,$$
where
$$B = b(a∪b)^* ∪ (a∪b)^*\\C = (a∪b)^*.$$
Similarly, we have
$$B = b(a∪b)^* ∪ ε ∪ a(a∪b)^* ∪ b(a∪b)^* = ε ∪ a(a∪b)^* ∪ b(a∪b)^* = ε ∪ aC ∪ bC\\
C = ε ∪ a(a∪b)^* ∪ b(a∪b)^* = ε ∪ aC ∪ bC.$$
where, in $B$, we make use of idempotency: $x∪x = x$ (as well as commutativity $x∪y = y∪x$ and associativity $(x∪y)∪z = x∪(y∪z)$). Thus, we also have the grammar
$$A → ε, A → aB, A → bC, B → ε, B → aC, B → bC, C → ε, C → aC, C → bC,A$$
with $A$ as the top-level expression, as indicated at the end.

That process is one and the same as that of deriving a deterministic finite state automaton from a regular expression.

Noting the equivalence of $B$ and $C$, this can be optimized by just setting $C = B$, to get:
$$A → ε, A → aB, A → bB, B → ε, B → aB, B → bB,A.$$
This, in turn, reveals the equivalence of $A$ and $B$, so it can be optimized yet further by setting $B = A$ to get:
$$A → ε, A → aA, A → bA,A.$$

That process is one and the same as that of minimalizing a deterministic finite state automaton.